# Gems load order in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to specify the gems load order in Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Have not looked at the code, but from my experience they load in the order specified in the Gemfile

e.g. if this is your Gemfile

```
gem 'c'
gem 'a'
gem 'b'
```

c will load before a